# Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions<Client>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

[image]

While creating a findOne request using typeorm i get this error, HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the TypeORM docs](https://typeorm.io/find-options#basic-options) you need to call `findOne` like this (assuming `clientId` is also the name of the column in the `Client` table).

```js
const client = await Client.findOne({
    where: {
        clientId: clientId
    }
});
```

The error message is telling you that it is expecting a `FindOneOptions<Client>` but you are giving it a `number` instead.

Comment: Type '{ clientId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Client> | FindOptionsWhere<Client>[] | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'clientId' does not exist in type 'FindOptionsWhere<Client> | FindOptionsWhere<Client>[]'.ts(2322)
FindOneOptions.d.ts(23, 5): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type 'FindOneOptions<Client>'

Comment: Same error is shown even after when i parse it into integer.

Comment: What is the name of the client ID column in the `Client` table? That error suggests that the column name in the code does not match the column name in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, client table had a diffrent name for id column.